# How to setup Android sdk from command-line on headless server?

Tags: android, sdk, installation, headless

So far Ive managed to download and install the SDK and its in my PATH. Problem now is that I can't run "android update sdk" since it expects to be connected to a display and Im connected to a remote headless server through ssh (its a build server so there's no desktop env). Is there a command-line option for the android tool that tells it to run without X ?

Comment: If on linux, you can check out these instructions: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Android-on-Ubuntu-Linux-With-Eclipse-Ide

Answer (score 36):

There is a `--no-ui` flag for the update.

Typical linux setup:

```
cd android-sdk-linux_86/tools
./android update sdk -u
```

This will run it headless. To note, `-u` and `--no-ui` are the same flag

Comment: FYI, --no-ui has *never* worked for me.

Comment: when run this command it's asking for username/password "Site Authentication
Please login to the following domain: Use your MOTODEV account email and passwor                                                                             d here to access the latest Motorola add-ons. Create a free MOTODEV account at d                                                                          eveloper.motorola.com.

Server requiring authentication:
android-sdk-addons.motodevupdate.com
Login:
Password:
" how to stop this keep prompting

Answer (score 4):

I just created a small command line tool that does the update in any environment (GUI or non-GUI). Didn't have the chance to test it extensively, but as far as I can tell it does what it should.

The command line tool updates a pre-installed base Android SDK with all currently available platforms, add-ons, extras, docs, samples and tools. This should be enough for a build server (I need this for my Hudson CI installation with Maven).

Please go here for more details:

http://code.google.com/p/android-sdk-tool

Comment: Just wanted to add that I successfully used the script above.