# "User Defined Sites" in Android SDK Manager via Command Line

Tags: android

I am attempting to add a User Defined Site to a headless installation of the android sdk.

I am able to get selective package updates working. Examples of what I am doing:
http://tools.android.com/recent/updatingsdkfromcommand-line

["android update sdk" on headless linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157089/android-update-sdk-on-headless-linux)

[How to setup Android sdk from command-line on headless server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684296/how-to-setup-android-sdk-from-command-line-on-headless-server)

This works fine, but I need to load a user-defined site into the sdk. If I load it via the GUI, then the packaged provided by the add-on site will be displayed when you do

```
./android list sdk
```

However, I can not find a way to actually add the site to the list of sources without going through the GUI.

The "User Defined Sites" is brought up by selecting Tools->Manage Add-on Sites in the Android SDK Manager and selecting the User Defined Sites tab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a workaround for this

after testing on a machine with the ui i have found that it created a file called "repositories.cfg"

so all you need to do is to create a file HOME_DIR/.android/repositories.cfg
with the content fitting to your needs in my case it was:

```
count=1
src00=https\://s3.amazonaws.com/android-sdk-manager/redist/addon.xml
```

The count here is the number of add-on sites you have on the machine.

Comment: We found this after much pain, but unfortunately it is not a really effective work-around: You can not always rely on a consistent HOME_DIR on remote jenkins machines.

It would be much better if there was a file in the android dist itself we could modify, but I believe the one in HOME is your only option :(.

I will accept for now because I believe there is no better workaround.

Comment: I actually looked on the source a couple of days back and it seems you can set ANDROID_SDK_HOME and create the .android directory in it
as the SDK will first search the ANDROID_SDK_HOME and only than will try other places.

Comment: That is useful. I will try it on our set up.